# Access Denied error on s3 with cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm starting to build a infrastructure on AWS, the first step is to make a Cloud Front service work with two different S3 buckets (I'm uploading a simple index.html to each bucket). For that I've made the following yaml to deploy via Cloud Formation.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  UserBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: my-user-bucket
      Tags:
        - Key: description
          Value: "User page files"
  AdminBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: my-admin-bucket
      Tags:
        - Key: description
          Value: "Admin page files"
  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'origin identity'                  
  UserBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: my-user-bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: 
              - 's3:GetObject'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                Fn::Join:
                  - " "
                  -
                    - "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity"
                    -
                      !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
            Resource: 
            - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::my-user-bucket/* 
    DependsOn:
      - UserBucket
  AdminBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: my-admin-bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: 
              - 's3:GetObject'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                Fn::Join:
                  - " "
                  -
                    - "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity"
                    -
                      !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
            Resource: 
            - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::my-admin-bucket/* 
    DependsOn:
      - AdminBucket               
  PublicDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - DomainName: my-user-bucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
          Id: S3-my-user-bucket
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginAccessIdentity: 
              'Fn::Join':
                - ''
                - - origin-access-identity/cloudfront/
                  - Ref: CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity       
        - DomainName: my-admin-bucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
          Id: S3-my-admin-bucket
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginAccessIdentity: 
              'Fn::Join':
                - ''
                - - origin-access-identity/cloudfront/
                  - Ref: CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          TargetOriginId: S3-my-user-bucket
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'false'
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
        CacheBehaviors:
        - PathPattern: user/*
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          TargetOriginId: S3-my-user-bucket
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'false'
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
        - PathPattern: admin/*
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          TargetOriginId: S3-my-admin-bucket
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'false'
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
        Enabled: 'true'
        Comment: Some comment
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
    DependsOn:
      - UserBucketPolicy
      - AdminBucketPolicy
```

As you can see I'm trying to redirect the requests for user and admin using the Cloud Front Distribution behavior configuration.

I'm able to access the index.html file at `foobar.cloudfront.net`, for me that means that the OAI is working fine. But both `foobar.cloudfront.net/admin/index.html` and `foobar.cloudfront.net/user/index.html` returns the error bellow, so I'm thinking that theres something wrong with the behavior and/or path:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>YRCKS4PAV9C11CR9</RequestId>
  <HostId>N9d3NJLrwZY1bECeTmXoQqRuDljsgFQk3C9pt5AX2pZyI4BEhTMCvJDB1uUAaQ4zUlppbvQbyOs=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any ideas of what is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to update your BucketPolicies to include both:

```
Action: 
  - 's3:GetObject'
  - 's3:ListObjects'
```

and

Resource to be both:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::my-user-bucket/",
"arn:aws:s3:::my-user-bucket/*"
```

Comment: what's the reason behind adding 's3:ListObjects' in addition to 's3:GetObject'?

Comment: ListObjects is literally the permission to see what's in the bucket.  GetObjects give permissions to retrieve an object.  I guess the granularity is that you could publish a url to an object and allow someone to download the item, yet not snoop around looking at everything in the bucket.